# BMI Calculator always returns 0 in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I've been trying to learn swift and decided to build a little BMI calculator just to get used to everything. I thought I had everything about figured out, but for some reason it just returns 0 every time. I can't quite understand why exactly. I feel like it might be something to do with the `@State var` s but, I'm not sure cause the ones that aren't for the `textinput`s seem to work just find.

This is what I've got:

```
 import SwiftUI



struct ContentView: View {

    @State var heightFeet: String = ""
    @State var heightInches: String = ""
    @State var weight: String = ""
    @State var bmi: String = ""
    @State var bmiText: String = ""
    @State var bmiDetail: String = ""

    var body: some View{

        VStack {
            VStack {
                VStack {
                    Text("BMI Calculator")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding(.top)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)

                }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 100)
                .background(Color.black)
                .shadow(radius: 10)

                VStack {
                    TextField("Enter height in feet", text: $heightFeet)
                        .padding(.all)
                        .frame(width: 300)
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                        .background(Color.clear)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .shadow(radius: 5)
                        .keyboardType(.numberPad)

                    TextField("Enter height in inches", text: $heightInches)
                        .padding(.all)
                        .frame(width: 300)
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                        .background(Color.clear)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .shadow(radius: 5)
                        .keyboardType(.numberPad)

                    TextField("Enter weight", text: $weight)
                        .padding(.all)
                        .frame(width: 300)
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                        .background(Color.clear)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .shadow(radius: 5)
                        .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(Color.gray)



                VStack {
                    Text(bmiText)
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    Text(bmi)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    Text(bmiDetail)
                        .padding(.all)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)


                }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .padding()
            }

            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    let heightInFeet = Int(self.heightFeet)
                    let heightInInches = Int(self.heightInches)
                    let weights = Int(self.weight)
                    let height = Int(heightInFeet! * 12 + heightInInches!)
                    let bmis = Int(weights! / (height * height) * 703)
                    self.bmi = "\(bmis)%"
                    self.bmiText = "Your BMI is"
                    if bmis > 30{
                        self.bmiDetail = "You are considered to be obese."
                    }
                    else if bmis > 25{
                        self.bmiDetail = "You are considered to be overweight."
                    }
                    else{
                        self.bmiDetail = "You are healthy!"
                    }

                }) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.square")
                        Text("Calculate")


                    }
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 60.0)
                    .padding(.vertical, 20)
                    .background(Color("button"))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    .shadow(radius: 5)
                    .padding(.vertical, 40)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 20)

                }
            }
            .background(Color.gray)

        }
        .frame(minWidth:0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .onTapGesture {

              self.endTextEditing()
        }
    }
}

extension View {
  func endTextEditing() {
    UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder),
                                    to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
  }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't probably calculate that in integers. Or at least first multiply by `703` and then divide by `(height * height)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the code, but your calculation.

```
let bmis = Int(weights! / (height * height) * 703)
```

Example:

weights = 100 kg
height = 76 inch

result ==>  100 / (76 * 76) * 703 ==> 100 / 5776 * 703 ==> 100 / 4060528 ==> ~0

You can change the formula to

703 * weight / height * height

to get the correct result.

For the formula see [www.cdc.gov](https://www.cdc.gov/healthyweight/assessing/bmi/childrens_bmi/childrens_bmi_formula.html)